# Can't award second bounty to same answer on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, mobile-web

Over on the Sci-fi Stack, I wanted to reward an existing answer that had already been rewarded with a bounty by someone else. So I put a bounty on the question.

When the time came to award the bounty, I could assign it to any answer, *except the one that already had one*.
All other answers had a link to award the bounty, except the one that already had had a bounty awarded to it.
When I switched to the full site, I could award the bounty just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting in the next build (rev 2015.10.29.2918, meta rev 2015.10.29.3801) this is fixed.